# doctrine order by match against score multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

Any idea how to add scores in the `ORDER BY` with doctrine query builder? The below query throws a `Expected end of string, got '+'` error.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->select(
                'partial i.{ '.$fields.' }',
                'partial c.{ id, title, description }',
                'partial c2.{ id }',
                'partial ch.{ id, name, icon, description }',
                'partial t.{ id, tagname }',
                "MATCH($searchFields) AGAINST(:searchTerm BOOLEAN) as score1",
                'MATCH(t.tagname) AGAINST(:searchTerm BOOLEAN) as score2'
            )
            ->join('i.categories', 'c')
            ->leftJoin('c.parent', 'c2')
            ->leftJoin('i.tags', 't')
            ->join('i.status', 's')
            ->join('c.channel', 'ch')
            ->join('ch.company', 'co')
            ->where("(MATCH($searchFields) AGAINST(:searchTerm BOOLEAN) > 5 OR MATCH(t.tagname) AGAINST(:searchTerm BOOLEAN) > 5 )")
            ->setParameters([
                'searchTerm' => $searchTerm.'*',
            ])
            ->orderBy('score1 + score2', 'DESC');
```

Comment: you should use comma  ( ,  ) instead of +  ->orderBy('score1 , score2', 'DESC'); if you want both DESC order.

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't sum the scores, I found the solution was to sum the scores in the select instead of the order by

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved it by simply adding the fields together. Doh.

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->select(
                'partial i.{ '.$fields.' }',
                'partial c.{ id, title, description }',
                'partial c2.{ id }',
                'partial ch.{ id, name, icon, description }',
                'partial t.{ id, tagname }',
                "(MATCH($searchFields) AGAINST(:searchTerm BOOLEAN) + MATCH(t.tagname) AGAINST(:searchTerm BOOLEAN)) as score"
            )
```